# Plotly.js Connecting Sankey Flows

Tags: plotly.js

I am trying to connect 2/3 flows, Value B and Value C, from a single source into a larger flow in a Sankey diagram, however one of the flows terminates on its own. New to Sankey diagrams so I apologize if this is a trivial, I couldn't seem to find the answer.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rdub1/re2pn3hj/16/

Code:

```
var chart = document.querySelector('.chart')
    var trace = {
        type: "sankey",
        orientation: "h",
        domain: {
            x: [0,1],
            y: [0,1]
        },
        node: {
            pad: 15,
            thickness: 30,
            line: {
            color: "black",
            width: 0.5
            },
        label: ["Source", "Value A", "Value B", "Value C", "Value B + C"],
            },

        link: {
            source: [0,0,0,2,3],
            target: [1,2,3,4,4],
            value:  [50,10,30,40]
        }
    }

    var trace = [trace]

    var layout = {
        title: "Simple Sankey",
        font: {
            size: 10
        }
    }

    Plotly.react(chart, trace, layout)
```

Comment: Do you still need help on this? If so, could you please update your question and clarify what the expected Sankey Flow should look like? I don't understand what you mean by "from a single source into a larger flow". Are you talking about multiple diagrams or a single diagram with multiple flows?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I ended up abandoning what I was trying to do but coming back to this with fresh eyes I think I should swap the end values for the middle values so it would be something like A -> B + C -> B, C. I was originally trying to map some convoluted cost flows that had multiple labels for similar but varying expenses and was trying to capture that. I'll revisit the data and see if anything new sticks out this time.